# Suppressing "Common subdirectories:" in diff command

Tags: linux, diff

I'm trying to use the diff command to see the difference between two directories, recursively.

`aDirectory` under directory `directory1` and `aDirectory` under directory `directory2`:

```
diff "directory1/aDirectory" "directory2/aDirectory"
```

Each of those have subdirectories and that's fine. For each common subdirectory I get this:

```
Common subdirectories: directory1/aDirectory/dir and directory1/aDirectory/dir
```

Because I have so many identically named subdirectories, notification about common subdirectories is annoying and makes the output unreadable.

All I want the diff command to show me are files/subdirectories that are different between those two directories (and their subdirectories), but not the ones that are the same. Is there a switch for that?

Comment: Same here. `--suppress-common--lines` seems not to work for directory comparisons.

Answer (score 13):

You need to supply the `-r` option to do a recursive diff.  Without it, `diff` is telling you that "directory1/aDirectory" and "directory2/aDirectory" both have a subdirectory called "dir".  However, it is not looking inside "dir", because you did not ask for recursive diff.

Try

```
diff -r "directory1/aDirectory" "directory2/aDirectory"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to take out the lines that say "Common subdirectories" you need to feed the result of your diff command into grep -v. So you end up with:

`diff -r <directory1> <directory2> | grep -v "Common subdirectories:"`

Comment: OP said "see the difference between two directories, recursively", so it seems `-r` is required.